# Significant delay between python function completion and return

Tags: python, optimization, scikit-learn, cython, cprofile

I've come across an issue I can't seem to diagnose, where a Python function doesn't return until a long time after it actually completes. A minimum example (edited to be simpler):

```python
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
import time

def mwe(n):
    start = time.time()
    a = KDTree([[1]]).query_radius([[1]]*int(n), 1)
    print(f'Function completed in: {time.time()-start:.2f} seconds')

start = time.time()
mwe(1e6)
print(f'Function returned after {time.time()-start:.1f} seconds')

start = time.time()
mwe(1e7)
print(f'Function returned after {time.time()-start:.1f} seconds')
```

Output:

```
Function completed in: 0.36 seconds
Function returned after 4.4 seconds

Function completed in: 3.75 seconds
Function returned after 44.0 seconds
```

At first I thought this could be a garbage collection issue, but adding `gc.disable()` doesn't have any effect. As well, if it were garbage collection, I would expect it to appear prominently in the profile output—but cProfile doesn't even recognize the problem exists:

```
         645 function calls (636 primitive calls) in 2.701 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        2    1.069    0.534    1.076    0.538 {method 'query_radius' of 'sklearn.neighbors._ball_tree.BinaryTree' objects}
    32/23    0.919    0.029    1.059    0.046 {built-in method numpy.core._multiarray_umath.implement_array_function}
        1    0.570    0.570    2.701    2.701 test_return_delay.py:6(test_loop)
        4    0.135    0.034    0.135    0.034 {method 'repeat' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        7    0.004    0.001    0.004    0.001 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
        5    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {built-in method numpy.arange}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.246    0.123 index_tricks.py:322(__getitem__)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.005    0.001 validation.py:96(_assert_all_finite)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 function_base.py:23(linspace)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.005    0.001 validation.py:629(check_array)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _array_api.py:168(_asarray_with_order)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 numerictypes.py:573(_can_coerce_all)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 validation.py:320(_num_samples)
       47    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.135    0.034 <__array_function__ internals>:177(repeat)
...
```

If I instead run cProfile as a module over the entire script (i.e., `python -m cProfile -s time test_return_delay.py`), it does at least show there's an issue, but it doesn't seem to give any indication where it's coming from as far as I can tell:

```
         788549 function calls (774939 primitive calls) in 12.372 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1   11.257   11.257   11.257   11.257 {method 'enable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
      808    0.173    0.000    0.173    0.000 {built-in method io.open_code}
     3514    0.124    0.000    0.124    0.000 {built-in method nt.stat}
      157    0.094    0.001    0.097    0.001 {built-in method _imp.create_dynamic}
      808    0.076    0.000    0.076    0.000 {built-in method marshal.loads}
      808    0.045    0.000    0.045    0.000 {method 'read' of '_io.BufferedReader' objects}
     6273    0.033    0.000    0.051    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:96(_path_join)
   1066/1    0.025    0.000   12.373   12.373 {built-in method builtins.exec}
      391    0.025    0.000    0.067    0.000 doccer.py:13(docformat)
1701/1692    0.020    0.000    0.086    0.000 {built-in method builtins.__build_class__}
  157/126    0.016    0.000    0.084    0.001 {built-in method _imp.exec_dynamic}
      399    0.011    0.000    0.019    0.000 doccer.py:180(indentcount_lines)
     1359    0.011    0.000    0.161    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1536(find_spec)
     9043    0.009    0.000    0.009    0.000 {method 'splitlines' of 'str' objects}
  499/100    0.009    0.000    0.025    0.000 sre_parse.py:494(_parse)
      809    0.009    0.000    0.009    0.000 {method '__exit__' of '_io._IOBase' objects}
    17871    0.009    0.000    0.009    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
      808    0.008    0.000    0.367    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:950(get_code)
   100236    0.008    0.000    0.008    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
 1013/842    0.007    0.000    0.337    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:921(_find_spec)
   1040/2    0.007    0.000    1.116    0.558 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1022(_find_and_load)
     9075    0.007    0.000    0.007    0.000 {method 'expandtabs' of 'str' objects}
      671    0.007    0.000    0.020    0.000 inspect.py:2280(_signature_from_function)
        1    0.006    0.006    0.006    0.006 memory.py:371(MemorizedFunc)
...
```

Where might the issue lie, or how can I further debug?

I've simplified the example and raised the [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/26873) on scikit-learn's repository. The fix *seems* to be to have KDTree (and the other nearest neighbor classes) generate nested lists like `scipy.spatial.KDTree` does, rather than the current method of using arrays as the nested object.

Comment: It pretty much has to be garbage collection; as far as I know, the deletion of local variables is the only variable-time operation happening between the last line of a function and the next line of the caller.  Note that `gc.disable()` only affects the *cyclic* garbage collector, not Python's normal reference counting mechanism.  To test: time an explicit `del` of the local variables of the function, one at a time.

Comment: You're right; if I add `del neighbors` at the end of the loop, the two times become the same. This might be better asked in a separate question or in scikit-learn's repo directly, but it leads to the question of how to free that data more efficiently - given it's taking 5x as long to free it as it does to create it.

Comment: funny when instead of `del` you use `neighbours = 1+1` - this *heavy* computation takes 3+seconds

Comment: You might try a C-level profiler to see if you can get more details. I've had success with `perf` for tracking down similar problems (although I use it fairly infrequently so can't remember what arguments to use off the top of my head)